# Select, TextArea and Button (bind)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have Select, TextArea and Button.
This is what I can’t do.
If you select items in Select, then click Button. The selected value from Select should be copied and TextArea will be added and the cursor should be placed on the next line.

I will be glad to receive any suggestions. you can even change the whole principle of operation.
Task. Me need to fill in the TextArea. Suggested options in Select.

I tried, but it didn't work...

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            id: null,
            title: '',
            filmItem: '',
            listFilms: [],
            data:
            [
                    { id: 1, title: 'title1' },
                    { id: 2, title: 'title2' },
                    { id: 3, title: 'title3' },
                    { id: 4, title: 'title4' }
            ]
        };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onChangeArea = this.onChangeArea.bind(this);
        this.addFilm = this.addFilm.bind(this);
        this.choice = this.choice.bind(this);
    }

    addFilm(film)
    {
        this.setState({
        listFilms:
            [...this.state.listFilms, film]
         });
    }

    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    onChangeArea = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value.split("\n") })
    }

    choice(title)
    {
        this.setState({filmItem: title,})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="row App-main">
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <select name="cars" size="4" >
                                {
                                    this.state.data.map(film =>
                                        <option selected value={film.title} >
                                            {film.title}
                                        </option>
                                    )
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button class="editButton" noClisk={() => this.addFlim(this.state.filmItem)}> button </button>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <textarea name="films" onChange={this.onChangeArea} value={this.state.listFilms.map(r => r).join("\n")} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
export default App;
```

Comment: Apart from the typos you need to lose the `<form>` because clicking the button will submit the form and thus reload the page.

Comment: Fixed lots of small errors: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cray-lb8qi (you can add the selected title to the textarea now using the button, errors among others: wrong `name` in select, no onChange, `value="{film.title}"` should lose the quotes, etc, etc)

Comment: I am so idiot. Thank you!!